# Historical Question about Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups, math-history

I couldn't find any historical information about Schur-Zassenhaus theorem in many books or even papers which mention this theorem.

I think, Schur proved that if $G$ is a finite group and if $N$ is normal abelian subgroup such that $|N|$ and $|G/N|$ are co-prime, then there is a subgroup (complement) $H$ such that $G=NH$ and $N\cap H=1$. Then Zassenhaus extended this theorem excluding assumption that $N$ is abelian. In the book "The Theory of Groups" by Zassenhaus, the extended theorem appears only with name of Schur.

The questions I would like to ask are historical, and I am posting here, since I couldn't find much about this theorem, anywhere.

**Q.1.** Give the name of the paper where Schur proved (t)his theorem first.

**Q.2.** Has Zassenhaus published the extended theorem before including in his book?

Zassenhaus gives the proof of the extended theorem in his book (p.162 in Dover Edition, and p.~132 in AMS Chelsea Edition). After the proof, he says,

"*It has been conjectured that any two complements of $N$ are conjugate in $G$*..."

Zassenhaus gives the proof of the conjuncture (in his book) in the following cases: i) $N$ is abelian; ii) $N$ is solvable; iii)$G/N$ is solvable.

Now, it is known that, the conjecture is true, in general. (See Groups and Representations- Alperin, Bell, p.84, and Exer. 2, p,104). My third question is

**Q.3** Where the proof of this conjecture appears first? (I mean, who proved the conjecture?)

Comment: Q3: The first proof of the conjecture was given by Feit and Thompson in their odd order theorem (no other proof was found yet).

Comment: Q1: According to the references in "The Theory of Finite Groups" by Kurzweil and Stellmacher Schur's paper should be "Schur, J.: Untersuchungen über die Darstellungen der endlichen Gruppen durch gebrochen lineare Substitutionen, J. reine u. angew. Math. 132 (1907), 85-137" as they usually cite the original papers (I didn't check). For the extended theorem by Zassenhaus they refer to the book.

Comment: Q2: I believe the book (1937) was its first publication. I dimly recall skimming every earlier paper (his first paper is 1934) and not finding it, but his papers contain a surprising variety of results. If you are just looking at dates though, I believe 1934-1937 is not a huge range, and he probably proved it during that time, as he took an important algebra course in 1933.

Comment: @Jack: Where did he take the algebra course? His algebra means "only group theory" or rings, fields, ... also?

Comment: University of Hamburg. I assume he studied finite dimensional algebras, finite and Lie groups, and algebraic number theory. He made important contributions in these fields, and his advisors did as well.

Comment: According to the articles about Hans Zassenhaus on wikipedia, his group theory book was based on lectures of his advisor Emil Artin and van der Waerden's algebra book was based on lectures by Artin and Emmy Noether.